# Python datetime.strptime month specifier doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

The month format specifier doesn't seem to work.

```
from datetime import datetime
endDate = datetime.strptime('10 3 2011', '%j %m %Y')
print endDate
2011-01-10 00:00:00 
endDate = datetime.strptime('21 5 1987', '%j %m %Y')
print endDate 
1987-01-21 00:00:00
```

Now, according to the manual [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> %m =  Month as a decimal number [01,12].

So, what am I missing, other than the hair I've pulled out trying to understand why my django __filter queries return nothing (the dates going in aren't valid!)? I've tried `03` and `05` to no avail.

Versions of things, platform, architecture et al:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7
$ python3 --version
Python 3.1.2
$ uname -r
2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (that's Linux/Fedora 14/64-bit).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't mix the `%j` with others format code like `%m` because if you look in the table that you linked %j is the Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366] so 10 correspondent to the 10 day of the year so it's 01 of January ...

So you have just to write :

```
>>> datetime.strptime('10 2011', '%j %Y')
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 10, 0, 0)
```

Else if you you wanted to use 10 as the day of the mount you should do :

```
>>> datetime.strptime('10 3 2011', '%d %m %Y')
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been sat in front of my screen for faaaar to long I think!

Comment: @Ninefingers: glad i was able to help :)

Comment: So how would I extract the date from a string that uses this format: `4/14/11 14:23`?

Answer (score 3):

Isn't `%j` the "day of year" parser, which may be forcing `strptime` to choose January 21, overriding the `%m` rule?

Answer (score 2):

`%j` specifies a day of the year.  It's impossible for the 10th day of the year, January 10, to occur in March, so your month specification is being ignored.  Garbage In, Garbage Out.