# how to set time variable in python, seasonal

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am learning python for a few days now and I have a hard time setting a variable as a time variable. I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

The variable is of the type: `pandas.core.series.Series`
And looks like the following:

```
2018S1;
2017S2;
2017S1
```

The idea is that python recognizes this as time data such that I can plot it and use it in regressions. I have searched on the forum and the internet but did not find any similar problem.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data consists of years and seasons.  For plotting purposes you could use a date (using typical year, month, day) in the middle of the season.

There is a post where someone was determining seasons based on date, it might give you some ideas  [Determine season given timestamp in Python using datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

For pandas periods have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

- If the last number means month, use `pd.Period(pp,freq='M')`
- If the last number means quarter, use `pd.Period(pp,freq='Q')`

The following workaround generates a pandas Series which you can use for regressions and more:

```
A = np.array(['2018S1', '2017S2', '2017S1'])
periods = []

for a in A:
    yr =a[0:4]
    ss =a[-1]
    pp = yr + '-' + ss
    periods.append(pd.Period(pp,freq='Q') )

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), periods)
ts
```

In the case of quarters we get:

```
2018Q1    0.531245
2017Q1   -0.126469
2017Q1    0.250046
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: float64
```

In the case of month we get:

```
2018-01    0.098571
2017-02    1.407439
2017-01   -0.406087
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```