# Sort a dataframe by day, but excluding the year

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataFrame with multiple years of data with a timestamp for each value. I am struggling with sorting data for summer/non-summer months. I am not sure how to tell pandas to get the data with dates June 15 to September 15, however discarding the year.

```
df['is_summer'] = df['Date'].dt.month.between(6,9) # This works for June 1 to September 30 for every year
# I want to do this, this is pseudo code
df['is_summer'] = df['Date'].dt.day.between(6-15,9-15) # From June 15 to September 15 for every year
# I also want to this 
df['is_late_night'] = df['Date'].dt.time.between(20:00,23:59) # From 20:00 to 23:59 for every day
```

I am having a difficult time finding the documentation for this. I want to know the correct syntax for the .between() for time, month, day, and year. 
Thank you for the help

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime

Comment: do you only want a solution using `.between`? there are other ways using mask and slice which are less messy than `.between`

Comment: Yes, I am interested in using mask and slice. I am not familiar with the concept, but most certainly interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask to filter the pandas dataframe, it will look something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# creating random date ranging across many years
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000,3)))
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=1000, freq='D')

# Creating the boolean mask to keep everything from June to August
mask = (df['date'].dt.month > 6) & (df['date'].dt.month <= 8)

# Applying the boolean mask to the data frame an printing it
print(df.loc[mask])
```

The mask creation can be embedded in the filtering step so in your case the solution is a one liner

```py
only_summer_data = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.month >= 6) & (df['date'].dt.month <= 8))
```

If you want to have the day too we get the following:

```py
start_mask = ((df['date'].dt.month == 6) & (df['date'].dt.day >= 15)) | (df['date'].dt.month > 6)

end_mask = ((df['date'].dt.month == 8) & (df['date'].dt.day <= 15)) | (df['date'].dt.month < 8)

mask = start_mask & end_mask
print(df.loc[mask])
```

However as the control over the date filtering are more fine grained, the boolean mask solution can get really verbose.

Comment: how does it know to filter 15 / 15 of June/Sept?

Comment: You can simply add two more condition where you check if the month is == 6 or 8 and that the day is bigger or smaller than 15. The mask will be containing 4 conditions.

Comment: `((df['date'].dt.month == 6 & df['date].dt.day > 15) | (df['date'].dt.month > 6) )& etc...`

Comment: but that will be > 15 for every month not starting at the 15th of June regardless of year?

Answer (score 1):

I would divide it into 3 simplier conditions

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2016', end='1/08/2018')})

select_month78 = df.date.dt.month.between(7,8)
select_month6 = (df.date.dt.month==6) & (df.date.dt.day >= 15)
select_month9 = (df.date.dt.month==9) & (df.date.dt.day <= 15)

df['is_summer'] = select_month78 | select_month6 | select_month9

df[df.is_summer]
```

Output:

```
          date  is_summer
166 2016-06-15       True
167 2016-06-16       True
168 2016-06-17       True
169 2016-06-18       True
170 2016-06-19       True
..         ...        ...
619 2017-09-11       True
620 2017-09-12       True
621 2017-09-13       True
622 2017-09-14       True
623 2017-09-15       True

[186 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`dayofyear`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-date-components) component to define the range and make comparisons - this will let you restrict the filter to a date range disregarding the year.

```
>>> start = pd.to_datetime('06-15-2000').dayofyear
>>> end = pd.to_datetime('09-15-2000').dayofyear
>>> start,end
(167, 259)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=52, freq='SM'),columns=['Date'])
>>> df[(df['Date'].dt.dayofyear >= start) & (df['Date'].dt.dayofyear <= end)]
         Date
11 2010-06-30
12 2010-07-15
13 2010-07-31
14 2010-08-15
15 2010-08-31
16 2010-09-15
35 2011-06-30
36 2011-07-15
37 2011-07-31
38 2011-08-15
39 2011-08-31
40 2011-09-15
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> df.loc[df['Date'].dt.dayofyear.between(start,end)]
```