# Subsetting columns of months by season in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a set of data that extracted from an excel sheet. one of the columns were dates and so I used `df.to_datetime()` to reformat the data. The data I have is only for the first day of each month, the string format is:

> "20190101"

so there are only 12 dates.

Then I used pd.pivot to make this column of dates the column labels.
The plan now is to subset the columns by seasons (e.g Jan, Feb, Dec is winter). I only have 2019 data but I will be using this code for future years. I will be taking Dec of previous year so I need to disregard the years.

How do I subset the columns based on the months. In other words I want to divide the DataFrame similarly to:

```
for column in full_df.iterrows()
    If (column_label.datetime.month = 01 | column_label.datetime.month = 02 |column_label.datetime.month = 12):
        winter_df[datetime.month] = full_df[column_label]
```

I know for loops are frowned upon in Dataframe, and I know I can hard-code it by keeping it as a string and typing in the specific strings, but the data will not be from the same year each time and I would have to adjust the code every year.
How do I do an if statement for column labels? `df.filter()` might be a good idea but I don't know if its possible with datetime object.

P.S. forgive me if I formed the question poorly or I don't understand your answer. Fairly new to pandas.

Update: I am looking to split the DataFrame into three based on month, The three periods of time are as follows:
Winter: January ,February ,December
Light load: March, April, May
Summer: June,July August, September

Comment: As you say Dec, Jan, Feb, I assume you want seasons in the northern hemisphere? Why not instead of months take the exact dates, as winter starts December 21st?

Comment: This question seems to have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime

Answer (score 0):

From your description this achieves what you want

1. categorises a quarter into a season
2. "pivots" actually transposes to column format

#### update

There seems to be a condition when `pandas` can give wrong quarter.  Can instead calculate from integer division on month

```
df = df.assign(season=lambda x: x["Date"].apply(lambda s: ["winter","spring","summer","autumn"][(s.month-1)//3]))
```

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame([{"Date":d, "Value": random.randint(10,20)} 
 for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2018,1,1),dt.datetime(2019,3,1), freq="MS")])

df = df.assign(season=lambda x: x["Date"].apply(lambda s: ["winter","spring","summer","autumn"][s.quarter-1]))
df = df.set_index(["season","Date"]).T
```

**output**

```
season     winter                           spring                           summer                           autumn                           winter                      
Date   2018-01-01 2018-02-01 2018-03-01 2018-04-01 2018-05-01 2018-06-01 2018-07-01 2018-08-01 2018-09-01 2018-10-01 2018-11-01 2018-12-01 2019-01-01 2019-02-01 2019-03-01
Value          10         20         12         17         12         12         11         20         11         19         12         10         11         20         14
```

Comment: In my case, this given the wrong seasons when I run `df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['20180624', '20180924', '20181225']})` and `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d') #, format='%Y%m%d'`.

Comment: it's wrong for me too with your data set... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html says the quarter. When I inserted `20180101` into you list it then got it right.  Have provided a different way to calc quarter... very odd !

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work for me because I'm not working on the typical seasons. I'm using the data to analyze power usage in my area and the three periods of time are as follows: Winter: January ,February ,December , Light load: March, April, May, Summer: June,July August, September