# A python program that tells the season of a given country (at the current time)

Tags: python

I have extremely basic knowledge of Python and I'm not asking for someone to make this for me. I just want a simple outline of steps that I would need to take to build this (assuming you were talking to someone that knew python).

Comment: Did you try any of the approaches in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a dict with countries and the location regarding the hemisphere, eg:

```
{"Netherlands": "North", "Brazil": "South", ...}
```

Step 2: get the current date:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
# e.g. datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 19, 19, 32, 20, 796000)
```

Step 3:

```
If your hemisphere is North:
    if month is in [June, July, Aug]:
        it is summer
.....

elif your hemisphere is South:
    if month is in [June, July, Aug]:
        it is winter
....
```

You get the point.