# How do I get my code to output "Winter is the season" when the user enters "March 19"?

Tags: python, dictionary

For this code, we're only allowed to use one if, nested for, and print statements. It basically has to output the season (northern hemisphere) based on the dates the user enters. These are the dates:

Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

Everything else on my code passed, but when I input March 19 the output is "Spring is the season". It should say "Winter is the season". This is code I have right now:

```
# Input

month = input("Enter Month: ")
day = int(input("Enter day of the month: "))

# Define the start and end dates for each season

seasons = {
    "Spring": ("March", 20, "June", 20),
    "Summer": ("June", 21, "September", 21),
    "Autumn": ("September", 22, "December", 20),
    "Winter": ("December", 21, "March", 19)
}

# Initialize the current season

current_season = "Invalid"

# Check if the input date is valid and determine the season

for season, (start_month, start_day, end_month, end_day) in seasons.items():
    if (month == start_month and (month != end_month or (day >=   start_day and day <= end_day))) or \
       (month == end_month and day <= end_day):
        current_season = season
        break

# Print the season

print(current_season, "is the season")
```

Comment: Please post your code again. The indentation was lost and the question wizard added backslash characters.

Comment: If `month == start_month` there's no need to check `month != end_month` since the start and end months are never the same.

Comment: You need some way to know that April and May are between March and June, so they're in the same season.

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier to use a dictionary whose keys are month names, not seasons.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime

Comment: Or you should list all the months in each season, e.g. `"Spring": [("March", 20, 31), ("April", 1, 30), ("May", 1, 31), ("June", 1, 20)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you ask the user to insert the number of month and day, the season can be returned as follows:
As you are restricted to only one *if* and *for*, by using the datetime module, you can easily get the days of the year when each season starts and ends and make a dictionary from them. Next, make a condition to see in which range the input of the user falls and then return the name of the season accordingly. The only bottleneck here is the winter period as it is not a continues number, which can be fixed by dividing the winter period to two parts (The second winter key in the dict has a space). The code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
spring_period = (datetime(2023, 3, 20).timetuple().tm_yday, datetime(2023, 6, 20).timetuple().tm_yday)
summer_period = (datetime(2023, 6, 21).timetuple().tm_yday, datetime(2023, 9, 21).timetuple().tm_yday)
autumn_period = (datetime(2023, 9, 22).timetuple().tm_yday, datetime(2023, 12, 20).timetuple().tm_yday)
winter_period1 = (datetime(2023, 12, 21).timetuple().tm_yday, 365)
winter_period2 = (1, datetime(2023, 3, 19).timetuple().tm_yday)
seasons = {"Spring":  spring_period, "Summer": summer_period, "Autumn": autumn_period, 
           "Winter": winter_period1, "Winter ": winter_period2}

month = int(input("Enter the month's number:"))
day = int(input("Enter day of the month:"))
day_of_year = datetime(2023, month, day).timetuple().tm_yday 
for season, dates in seasons.items():
    if dates[0] <= day_of_year <= dates[1]:
        print(season)
```

If, we did not have the datetime module and could not easily calculate the day of the year, we could use a more laborious strategy as follows:

```
month = int(input("Enter the month's number:"))
day = int(input("Enter day of the month:"))
if 3 <= month <= 6:
    if month == 3 and day >= 20 or month == 6 and day <= 20:
        print("Spring")
    elif 3 < month < 6 : 
        print("Spring")

if 6 <= month <= 9:
    if month == 6 and day >= 21 or month == 9 and day <= 21:
        print("Summer")
    elif 6 < month < 9 : 
        print("Summer")

if 9 <= month <= 12:
    if month == 9 and day >= 22 or month == 12 and day <= 20:
        print("Autumn")
    elif 9 < month < 12 : 
        print("Autumn")

if month == 12 or month <= 3:
    if month == 12 and day >= 21 or month == 3 and day <= 19:
        print("Winter")
    elif month < 3: 
        print("Winter")
```

And if you want to use it for an infinite loop in a software until it is interrupted at anytime by entering for example 0, you can write something like:

```
active = True
while active:
    month = int(input("Enter the month's number: \n Enter 0 to exit."))
    if month == 0:
        active = False
        print("Exit")
    else:
        day = int(input("Enter day of the month: \n Enter 0 to exit."))
        if day == 0:
            active = False
            print("Exit")
        else: 
    
            if 3 <= month <= 6:
                if month == 3 and day >= 20 or month == 6 and day <= 20:
                    print("Spring")
                elif 3 < month < 6 : 
                    print("Spring")

            if 6 <= month <= 9:
                if month == 6 and day >= 21 or month == 9 and day <= 21:
                    print("Summer")
                elif 6 < month < 9 : 
                    print("Summer")

            if 9 <= month <= 12:
                if month == 9 and day >= 22 or month == 12 and day <= 20:
                    print("Autumn")
                elif 9 < month < 12 : 
                    print("Autumn")

            if 12 == month or month <= 3:
                if month == 12 and day >= 21 or month == 3 and day <= 19:
                    print("Winter")
                elif month < 3: 
                    print("Winter")
```